# How to add or remove a UIView with dissolve animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewanimation

I know about `UIView:tranisitionFromView:ToView` with the option for `UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve`

but I have a view that is added to a view hierarchy and `alpha = 0;`

I want to set `alpha = 1` in an animated manner using the cross dissolve effect

How can I achieve this? I am not replacing any views in the hierarchy and therefor the first method isn't relevant

Comment: can you provide some code that you have done??

Answer (score 3):

Use `UIView`'s `animateWithDuration:animations:` method

set alpha relatively if you want to hide or show inside the `animations:` block

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
        view.alpha = 1;
    } completion:nil];
```

Also, when hiding the view, maybe you would want to remove it from super view in the completion block.